# get the value in checkbox per select in jquery using codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, checkbox

Hi i have this checkbox select and my button when saved the data i use .click function. My problem is i want to get the value of the checkbox based on what youve clicked say for example i have this checkbox data

```
ap-apartment
hs-house
lf-loft
as-asdsad
```

when i clicked the ap-apartmen,hs-house,lf-loft and clicked submit i want to get their valued based on what ive selected. My checkbox data is dynamic based on what the user added. Here's my checkbox view
  
                                Property Type:

```
                                <?php foreach($propertyType as $propType): ?>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="propertyType[]" id="propertyType" value="<?php echo $propType->id;?>" > <?php echo $propType->itemkey."-".$propType->itemvalue;?><br>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

```
 <button type="button" id="propertyButton" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
```

my jquery code

```
     $("#propertyButton").click(function(){

                $('input[name^="propertyType"]').each(function() {
                        alert($(this).val());
                });
});
```

the alert will get all the value in a checkbox even if only i check only one data. can someone help me figured this thing out? any help is muchly appreciated.TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [:checked](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector

```
$('input[name^="propertyType"]:checked').each(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

This will get you only the checked checkboxes

**Update**

To alert the checked checkbox values at once, simply concatenate them, then alert

```
var checkedVals = '';
$('input[name^="propertyType"]:checked').each(function() {
        checkedVals+=$(this).val();
        checkedVals+='-';
    });

checkedVals = checkedVals.substring(0, checkedVals.length - 1);//remove last '-'
alert(checkedVals);
```

Comment: ok thanks it works ummm how will i able to do this the values say for example the data value ive checked is 8,9,10 i want to do it into this way
8-9-10

Comment: @user1718865, do you mean you want to alert all the values at once?

Comment: yes based on what ive checked cause the alert($this).val()); will alert 8 then alert 9 then alert 10 i want that when i checked it will get 8-9-10